# swf(flash) plays automatically in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, flash

I embed the swf file by [swfobject](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html). I do not want the swf file(it's an advertisement) play automatically, so I set the attribute of play with "false". as following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="970" height="250" id="myFlashContent">
                <param name="movie" value="day_110702/ad.swf" />
                <param name="play" value="false" /> 
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="day_110702/ad.swf" width="970" height="250">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly on IE but it doesn't work on Chrome/Firefox. In Chrome/Firefox the swf file plays automatically.

In addition, another behavior of swf file differ from Chrome/Firefox and IE is:
when you embedded the swf file with invisible iframe tag. as

```
<iframe id="iframe"  src="swf.html" style="width:100%;height:100%; display:none; visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

When you browse the page that contains this iframe in IE/Firefox, the swf will NOT play until you make iframe visible. But if yo browse the page in Chrome, the swf will play automatically even if iframe is invisible.

Anyone can tell me why the swf(flash) behavior is differ in different browsers?
Cross-browsers problem always make crazy :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding the SWF using dynamic publishing instead of static publishing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.play = "true";
            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("day_110702/ad.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "970", "250", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myAlternativeContent">
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks PaulT, but it's not the answer I want to know. What I want to know is why Flash behavior is differ between browsers.